# Matrix fscanf assembly x86 MASM

Tags: assembly, matrix, masm, scanf

I am trying to read a matrix of integers with fscanf in assembly x86 , and for some reason at the end of my program I have only 1 element in the matrix...

Here's my code:

```
; edit ;var=number of elements*4 
;m is my matrix defined : m dd ?
;format db "%d",0
mov edi,0
readm:
    add m,edi
      cmp edi,var
      jg close

    push offset m
    push offset format 
    push esi
    call fscanf
    add esp,12  

add edi,4

jmp readm   
close:
```

Thanks in advance.
New to assembly ^.^
Ok, so the whole problem is reduced to 2 questions:

1. How to declare an uninitialized matrix (I don't know the dimensions)
2. How to go to the next element of the matrix(This doesn't seem to work:

   ```
    mov ebx,[m]
    inc ebx
    mov [m],ebx
   ```

It might not work because my matrix isn't declared a matrix.. or idk..)

EDIT #2: After some help from a friend I made it work, new problem, since I don't how big to declare my matrix, and it ends up having a lot of zeros after my values (since I declared it bigger) How to re-declare my matrix or something after I found out the number of lines and columns?

Comment: The instruction `add m,edi` adds EDI to the value in the first element of the matrix, storing the result in the first element of the matrix. It doesn't change the offset of `m`, as its location in memory is fixed. Also if `var` is the number of elements you'll only read in a quarter of them because you increment EDI by 4.

Comment: Var is the number of elements * 4 , my bad(forgot to write that). And I as thinking thats the problem.Do you have any idea how to change the program , so it works?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the fault, rather than describing it in comment. For example `m dd ?` defines *one* uninitialised variable: not a matrix.

Comment: Uhh , how to declare an uninitialised matrix then ?

Comment: All I want is to read a matrix from a file.The number of lines and coloum are read from the file as well but that works.(Thats how I got my number of elements).

Comment: @NicuD: `how to declare an uninitialised matrix then?`  With `resd` in the bss section, or with `dd` in the data section like you did.  The problem isn't how you declare it, it's that you're doing `m[0]+=4` rather than `char*p=m; ... ; p+=4`.  If you wrote `add  offset m, 4`, like you'd need to for your plan to work because you're using MASM with its confusing syntax that doesn't require `[square brackets]` for memory access, it wouldn't assemble.

Comment: @Peter Cordes what's resd?Yes add offset m,4 won't work.... any idea how to do it... I don't know  what to try anymore...

Comment: Get the address into a register and increment that.  (and `resd` is reserve dword, like a quick search of your assembler manual should tell you.)  see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for some links.  It looks like you need to find a tutorial or something that walks you through some basics.  This stuff is already written down.

Comment: Ok so something like this :mov ebx,[m]      inc ebx          mov [m],ebx                     and m resd 100 , gives me an error...(Syntax error)

Comment: @PeterCordes : _MASM_ doesn't have _RESD_ but is the equivalent of _DD_ . You use the _DUP_ directive on _DD_ to allocate a block. Example: `m DD  100  DUP (?)` would create a block of 100 *DWORD*s that are uninitialized. `m DD  100  DUP (0)` would create a block of 100 *DWORD*s initialized to 0.

Comment: As for the question about allocating a matrix of a specific size at runtime - Since you are using `fscanf`, you have the _C_ library available. You can call [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) which allocates a specified number of bytes. So if you managed get the number of rows and columns, and you know each element is 4 bytes (*DWORD*) in size - you can call `malloc` with the value (rows*columns*4) as the parameter & that will allocate that many bytes on the heap and return a pointer to that memory in _EAX_. Use `calloc` instead if you also want the memory zeroed

Comment: Once you are done with a `malloc`ed (or `calloc`ed) memory region, to free it up you can call [free](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/) passing it the pointer to the memory area returned by `calloc` or `malloc`.